# Using REST-Services - first time takes much longer as follow calls

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-3.5

I use a REST-Services which needs Bacis-Authentication on the following way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        var url = "http://172.34.1.111:8088/ustrich/rest/projects/pid/1234";
        using (var wc = this.CreateWebClient(url)) {
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            var s = wc.DownloadString(url);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            this.label1.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
            this.textBox1.Text = s;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        this.textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}

protected WebClient CreateWebClient(string url) {
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var cache = new CredentialCache { { new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("rest", "rest") } };
    webClient.Credentials = cache;
    webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    return webClient;
}
```

The problem is now, when I start my Test-Application and execute this code, the first time it takes about 5 seconds on wc.DownloadString(url). The follow calls, when I click the second etc. time on the button, it takes only 300ms. 
Now my question: Is there something wrong in my code? Can I optimize something there to resolve the problem that it takes 5 seconds on first call?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's just how IIS works, new content has to be processed on first hit.

Comment: What type of app is Test-Application?

Comment: Is you app taking 5s or is the RESTful API taking 5s on the first hit?

Comment: my app (the code above) is a windows-forms-application. When I hit the REST-API (at wc.DownloadString(url)) the first time after starting my app it takes 5s till the response. After that it takes only 300ms (when I reply with click on my button). When I restart my Test-Application, it takes 5s at the first call wc.DownloadString(url) and 300ms each after call till a restart of my Test-Application.

Comment: Are you using RestSharp to do the requests?  This is exactly what happens to me.  Server stays the same doesn't get restarted.  The first client request takes a good 5 seconds, after that it's instant.

Comment: No, I am using .NET-WebClient and Parse the Result myself. Are you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you hit the code, it gets precompiled. It will always be slow this time. I believe you can use MSBUILD to do this when you build your code but that's just transferring the time to a different part of the process. In production, this will only happen each time the worker process restarts.

Comment: Hi flem - mmhh - what will be precompiled after the programm is running and it call wc.DownloadString(url)? - On this time, the application is already precompiled.

Comment: @t.kehl. You COMPILE your code. The first time it is hit in IIS it is PRECOMPILED. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx).

Comment: the REST-service is a PHP-Restservice running in a apache. It will not be stopped and restarted between my tests. But always after starting my test-application and hit the REST-Service the first time, it will take much longer as following times.